# How to use the Cartographic Composer of GRASS 6.4.3?

Tags: grass-gis, cartography, printing, imagery

Following on from my previous question (which was, again, how to use the Cartographic Composer)...

I've got a GIS in GRASS. I need to print various bits of it. Problem is, it needs images on it whenever we print it - the logos of our clients and stuff.

Now, I've managed to get the Cartographic Composer to show the logo images, now I just need it to show the map - or more rather, the Map Display and what that is currently showing. As everyone who will be using the GIS is used to ArcMap (but it would cost too much to get the licences), we basically want it so that the user can just press the print button and GRASS will print out the Map View, plus the logos.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the documentation and video tutorials in the Wiki:

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Cartographic_Composer

Images can be embedded (probably as EPS files, see the manual).